# Setting field shown for attribute pop up with multiple layers in QGIS Cloud

Tags: popup, qgis-cloud

I have a web map in QGIS cloud with several layers that intersect.  When I click on an area, I get the gray attribute pop up window showing me the layers that have features overlapping there, like this:

[image]

However, I want to be able to set the field the pop-up window shows. In the example here it showed "428" for Subdivisions which is the `qc_id`, but I would rather it showed "subdivisions". Under Parcels, it shows owner names whereas I would rather it show me Folio numbers.

Is there any way to change those fields to show different initial values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within QGIS you can edit the layer properties for the layer you want to switch and it is under the "Display" tab.  Use drop down menu to set what field you want it to display.

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be found here: https://docs.qgiscloud.com/en/#ogc-webservices-with-qgis-cloud

Here's the text that's important from the link:

Each layer that is uploaded with the QGIS Cloud Plugin into a QGIS Cloud database gets the field qc_id added during the upload process. field qc_id during the upload process. This field is filled with a database sequence filled in. This means that for each newly captured object in the layer the field qc_id is filled with a unique numerical value. Since you usually do not know which numbers are already used in the table. the table, the field qc_admin must not appear in the processing. processing. So the display of the field qc_id must be prevented. **You can set this in the Properties of the layer -> Attribute form. Under Fields select the field qc_id and change the control type to Hidden.**

You also need to prevent the qc_id field from being published via WFS. **By selecting Do not disclose via WFS in Layer Properties -> Fields in the configuration of the field qc_id select do not expose via WFS.**