# Feature info in QGIS Cloud

Tags: qgis, cloud-gis

By clicking on a point on a map at a detected site, numerical values appear from a qc_id field automatically generated in the layer, in the attached SS showing the value 16.
I would like the value of another field to appear instead: could you show me how to operate in QGIS to bring up the values of the other airports_q field?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here: [In qgis cloud, how can I set what field is shown for attribute pop up with multiple layers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/253229/in-qgis-cloud-how-can-i-set-what-field-is-shown-for-attribute-pop-up-with-multi)

Basically, in QGIS open "Properties" of your layer, select the tab "Display" and in section "Display Name" select the attribute you want to be shown in qgiscloud as the field name.